3D Triangle doesn’t rotate properly with Camera
I have been trying to make a program where I can enter three coordinates in a right-handed coordinate system that will then form a triangle while a camera rotates around the triangle. From my understanding, these are the steps I have to follow:
1. Create a projection matrix using perspective projection:
std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> CreateProjectionMatrix(float fov, float aspectRatio, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {
    float f = 1.0f / std::tan((fov * 3.141 / 180) / 2.0f);
    std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> projectionMatrix = {
        f / aspectRatio, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, (farPlane + nearPlane) / (nearPlane - farPlane), (2.0f * farPlane * nearPlane) / (nearPlane - farPlane),
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    return projectionMatrix;
}

2. Create a view/camera matrix (I got the code from this website:
here)
std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> createViewMatrix(
    Vec4<float> cameraPosition,
    float pitch, float yaw, float roll) {

    pitch = toRadians(pitch);
    yaw = toRadians(yaw);
    roll = toRadians(roll);

    float cosPitch = cos(pitch);
    float sinPitch = sin(pitch);
    float cosYaw = cos(yaw);
    float sinYaw = sin(yaw);


    Vec4<float> xaxis( cosYaw, 0, -sinYaw );
    Vec4<float> yaxis(sinYaw * sinPitch, cosPitch, cosYaw * sinPitch);
    Vec4<float> zaxis(sinYaw * cosPitch, -sinPitch, cosPitch * cosYaw);

    std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> viewMatrix = {
        xaxis.x(),            yaxis.x(),            zaxis.x(),      0,
        xaxis.y(),            yaxis.y(),            zaxis.y(),      0,
        xaxis.z(),            yaxis.z(),            zaxis.z(),      0,
        -dot(xaxis, cameraPosition), -dot(yaxis, cameraPosition), -dot(zaxis, cameraPosition), 1
    };
   

    return viewMatrix;
}

3. Create a Model matrix. In this case, I don’t have to use one because all my points are almost centered in the middle of the coordinate system, but I might be wrong here.
4. Multiply all my matrices in the right order, which should be:
PointsB = Point * (projectionMatrix * viewMatrix)
This is my current Code:

//inputs

float CAMERA_X = 0;
float CAMERA_Y = 0;
float CAMERA_Z = 0.5;
float FOV = 90;

const float ASPECT_RATIO = 16.0f / 9.0f;
const float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;
const float FAR_PLANE = 1000.0f;

float CAMERA_Y_ANGLE = 45.f;

//points
Vec4 p1(-100, 0, 0); //funktion outputs: 360 259
Vec4 p2(100, 0, -100); //funktion outputs: 398 305
Vec4 p3(100, 0, 100); //funktion outputs: 394 301


Vec2D<float> Project(Vec4<float> point) {

 auto projectionMatrix = CreateProjectionMatrix(FOV, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE);
 auto viewMatrix = createViewMatrix(Vec4<float>(0, 0, 0), 0, CAMERA_Y_ANGLE, 0);

 auto ViewProj = MultiplyMatrices(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

 Vec4<float> projectedPoint(
     point.x() * ViewProj[0][0] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][0] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][0] + ViewProj[3][0],
     point.x() * ViewProj[0][1] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][1] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][1] + ViewProj[3][1],
     point.x() * ViewProj[0][2] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][2] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][2] + ViewProj[3][2],
     point.x() * ViewProj[0][3] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][3] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][3] + ViewProj[3][3]
 );

 if (projectedPoint.w() != 0.0f) {
     projectedPoint.set_x(projectedPoint.x() / projectedPoint.w());
     projectedPoint.set_y(projectedPoint.y() / projectedPoint.w());
     projectedPoint.set_z(projectedPoint.z() / projectedPoint.w());
 }

 //my Window has a size of 800 * 600 and becouse my points are negative this is a 'emergency solution'
 return VectorHelpers<float>(projectedPoint.x() + 400, projectedPoint.z() + 300);
}

This only appears to rotate the triangle in the center of the window and not that the camera moves around the object. My current guess is that some points need to be relative to some other point or that I’m mixing different coordinate systems. Any help is very appreciated, including code.
Thanks in advance!
edit:
the triangle on the left side is currently rotating around itself on the Y-axis. What I want is that the camera moves around the triangle as shown on the right side. For example, if the camera is rotated by 180 degrees on the Y-axis, the triangle shouldn’t be visible because the camera is looking away from the triangle.
picture example: 
Solution
The main problem was with my projection and view matrix. This is my code now, which works fine, although there is no clipping, which is why objects close to the camera might appear weird. (rewrote it to use a left handet coordinate system):
std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> createViewMatrix(
    Vec4<float> cameraPosition,
    Vec4<float> cameraTarget,
    Vec4<float> cameraUpVector) {
    Vec4<float> A = Normalize(cameraPosition - cameraTarget);
    Vec4<float> B = Normalize(Cross(cameraUpVector, A));
    Vec4<float> C = Cross(A, B);
    std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> viewMatrix = {
        B.x(),                      C.x(),                      A.x(),                      0,
        B.y(),                      C.y(),                      A.y(),                      0,
        B.z(),                      C.z(),                      A.z(),                      0,
        -dot(B, cameraPosition),    -dot(C, cameraPosition),    -dot(A, cameraPosition),    1
    };
    return viewMatrix;
}
std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> CreateProjectionMatrix(float fov, float aspectRatio, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {
    float f = 1.0f / std::tan((fov * 3.141 / 180) / 2.0f);
    std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> projectionMatrix = {
        f / aspectRatio, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, farPlane / (nearPlane - farPlane), -1,
        0.0f, 0.0f, (nearPlane * farPlane) / (nearPlane - farPlane), 0.0f
    };
    return projectionMatrix;
}
Vec2D<float> Project(Vec4<float> point) {
    std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 4> ObjectMatrix = {
        1,0,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,1
    };
    auto projectionMatrix = CreateProjectionMatrix(FOV, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE);
    auto viewMatrix = createViewMatrix(CameraPosition, 
                                       CameraTarget,
                                       CameraUpVector);
    auto ViewProj = ObjectMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
    Vec4<float> projectedPoint(
        point.x() * ViewProj[0][0] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][0] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][0] + ViewProj[3][0],
        point.x() * ViewProj[0][1] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][1] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][1] + ViewProj[3][1],
        point.x() * ViewProj[0][2] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][2] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][2] + ViewProj[3][2],
        point.x() * ViewProj[0][3] + point.y() * ViewProj[1][3] + point.z() * ViewProj[2][3] + ViewProj[3][3]
    );

    projectedPoint.set_x(projectedPoint.x() / projectedPoint.z());
    projectedPoint.set_y(projectedPoint.y() / projectedPoint.z());

    if (projectedPoint.z() < 0.01) {
        //dont draw points
        return Vec2D<float>(0, 0);
    }

    auto x = projectedPoint.x() * 600.f + 600.f / 2.0f;
    auto y = -projectedPoint.y() * 600.f + 600.f / 2.0f; //600 * 600 is my window size
    return Vec2D<float>(x, y);
}


please show a [mre], a screenshot or animated GIF might also help illustrate your problem

added an image link I hope it helps
